# Спряжение глаголов с ударными личными окончаниями

Tags: грамматика

Как объяснить иностранцам и всем тем, кто со слуху не различает ударные личные  окончания глаголов, в каких случаях глагольное личное окончание ударное? Есть ли какие-нибудь способы?

Comment: "кто не различает ударные личные окончания глаголов". Имеется в виду, что они со слуха не могут понять, куда падает ударение в слове?

Comment: Да, именно так. На письме -то легко различить.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: А как на письме различить, если ударение не стоит?

Comment: А на письме и не надо: я спросил для того, чтобы знать, как объяснить написание личных окончаний  тем, кто не различает их на слух.

Comment: А, теперь понял вроде. Значит, это нужно для того, чтобы они могли правильно **писать** окончания? Это у вас в Армении с этим проблемы у местных? :)

Comment: Да, у многих. Но я спрашивал не только для того, чтобы объяснить армянам, но и любым иностранцем, если вдруг придется заниматься.

Comment: См.: в глагол сп-ишь  относится ко второму спряжению, здесь спряжение определяется по личным окончаниям. А те, кто не разлзичает эти ударные окончания, не смогут определить тип спряжения.

Comment: Не знаю, плохо это или нет, но я никогда не знал этих спряжений и правил. Пишу по интуиции. То есть непонятно, если я и без этих знаний пишу достаточно грамотно, нужно мне это знать, например, чтобы другим можно было объяснить, или нет...